# Record IP Address of user when they log in with Devise (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ip

I'm using Devise to handle my authentication for my site.  Is there a way I can add a function to record a user's IP address when they log into my app?

We are just trying to see where people are logging in from.

Thanks

**Edit**

It's been pointed out that the devise user model watches the current and last_ip of the logged in user.  I want to keep a record of every login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Warden hooks inside of `User.rb` to do whatever you want.

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do|record, warden, opts|
  logger.info("sign in at: #{record.current_sign_in_at}, #{record.current_sign_in_ip}")
  record.account_logins.create!(ipAddress: record.current_sign_in_ip)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

devise stores the current and last ip address of the user automatically in user table. The column names it uses are `current_sign_in_ip`, `last_sign_in_ip`. To track all the sessions of a user you could use https://github.com/shenoudab/devise_traceable

Comment: is this the effect of the :trackable symbol in the user model? It's a default when you use devise, but if you remove it, I wonder if it will stop logging IPs...

Comment: Yes you are right. From devise documentation 'Trackable: tracks sign in count, timestamps and IP address.'

Comment: I want to create a running history of where a user has logged in from.  This way, I can se that a user logged in from California today and Colorado last week.  The currentIP gets overwritten on every login, right?

Comment: yes by default devise will store only the current and the last ip addresses. But you might want to checkout https://github.com/shenoudab/devise_traceable gem

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That's really close to what I want to be able to do.  Only problem is it waits until you log out to log the entry.

Comment: overriding the hooks.rb should make it customizable for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `request.ip` or `request.remote_ip` to see an IP address. See [link](https://www.abstractapi.com/guides/how-to-get-an-ip-address-using-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33892463)